# Push Content Off Canvas Using jQuery Animate

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

How do i add the [.css method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to this jQuery so it pushes the content off canvas rather than overlays the sidebar over the content.

```js
jQuery(function( $ ){

$('.button').click(function() {

    $('.sidebar').animate({
         width: 'toggle'}, 
        'slow'
        );

  });

});
```

```css
.sidebar {
     width: 350px;
     height: 100%;
     position: fixed;
     background-color: #f5f5f5;
     display: none;
     padding: 20px;
}

.content {
     width: 700px;
     float: right;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Toggle</button>
<div class="sidebar">
This is the slide out sidebar content
</div>

<div class="content">
This is the main content area. This is the main content area. This is the main content area. This is the main content area. This is the main content area. This is the main content area.
</div>
```

I was thinking something like this might work but not sure how to include it with the existing [.animate method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) in jQuery:

```
$('.content').css('marginLeft') = '350px';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery(function( $ ){
  var counter = 0;
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $('.sidebar').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 'slow');
    if(counter === 0) {
     $('.content').animate({width: 300}, 'slow');
     counter++ ;
    } else {
    $('.content').animate({width: 700}, 'slow');
    counter-- ;
    }
  });
});
```

You can do Jquery code like this.Sample => https://fiddle.jshell.net/27n3kvdu/